# Why is beforeValidate not called if its in the base class

Tags: grails, groovy

This has just cost me almost half a day (mostly du to the fact that Grails/Gorm isnt exactly very vocal about the error that happens)

I have to domain classes where one inherits from the other

```
class Base {
    String a

    static constraints = {
        a blank: false, nullable: false, unique: true
    }
}

class Extended extends Base {
    String b

    static constraints = {
        b blank: false, nullable: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

Now I have also a `beforeValidate` method that acts on property `a`defined in `Base`.

```
def beforeValidate() {
    if (a == null) { a = "somevalue" }
}
```

If I create an instance of `Extended` and save it

```
def instance = new Extended()
instance.save()
```

Everything will work fine if `beforeValidate` is defined within `class Extended`.

However if I put `beforeValidate` into `class Base` it will fail (silently).

Why?

PS: grails 2.4.0 is used

Comment: Did you also try using `Base instance = new Extended()`?

Comment: nope. Why do you think this would help?

Answer (score 0):

If the base class is not in `grails-app/domain`, the event handler will not be called.  For example, if the project is structured like this, the event handler will be ignored:

```
src
    groovy
        mypackage
            Base.groovy
grails-app
    domain
        mypackage
            Extended.groovy
```